# Image problem : Can't Open with... Preview

Tags: finder, preview

On Mojave 10.14.6, selecting jpgs on a server but I can't use **Open with... > Preview**

Preview is the default app for jpgs, and 'Open with' is working fine with other file types and apps.

Any idea what's the cause and fix?

Comment: What does Get Info show for one of the affected files? What is the file extension: .jpg or .jpeg?

Comment: The filename extension is .JPG, and in Get Info > Kind : JPEG

Comment: Can you copy one of these images off the server and onto your desktop to confirm if that works or not?

Comment: I get : The operation can't be completed because one or more required items can't be found. (Error code -43)

Comment: Do any of these files contain special characters or are they simply alphanumeric?

Comment: No special characters.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues at play here.

1. The first is a file association issue. If you right-click the file, and choose Open With, does it show Preview (default) at the top? If *not*, then it's a file association issue.

[image]

2. The second is either a) file permissions issue; or b) corrupt file. For instance, you may be able to view the file listing on the remote share, but not actually access the file itself. To verify that either of these issues are not a concern, copy the remote file to your Desktop and try to open it locally. If you get an error copying the file, then you know it is a file permissions/accessibility issue. If you can copy it, but it fails to open properly in Preview, then you just have a corrupt file.

Comment: As written in the question and in comments, Preview is the default and I can't copy to finder (error -43).

Comment: @SamuelMartin OK. In that case, the issue is #2 as I described. It has nothing to do with Preview. The fact is that you're unable to access the file at all. This external drive - is it formatted as a Windows drive? Are you able to access other files in the same folder? It sounds like either a corrupt drive, a permissions issue, or something related.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the following folder from your Library of the user. To see the hidden Library, try the keyboard combination of <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>

```
Containers/com.apple.Preview

Containers/com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper
```

Restart and test.

Comment: Deleted /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview  and
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper
Rebooted.
Finder is now crashing repeatedly. Rainbow wheel and (not responding).

Comment: Have you rebooted your computer?

Comment: Yes. I edited my comment above to include 'Rebooted'.

Comment: The two folders were unexistent after restart. I opened Preview, found a jpeg on another disk and did a quick preview. Restarted. The com.apple.Preview folder is back. Finder crashes when accessing the disk on which my problem jpegs are sitting.